# PHP if / else statements don't seem to work

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I've created some if / else statements to get name from url like http://website.com/page.php?name=Love It seems to look good and trows no errors, but for some reason I am not getting data from the database. Basically it gets 'name' from url and checks of it is one of allowed categories, if yes it selects article from database that has st_category = to what user selected.
But than again for some reason it doesn't work.

Here is a snippet of code that I think causes the problem.

```
       <?php
        $category = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#i', '', $_GET["name"]);

        if ($category = "Love") {
        $st_category = "Love";
        }
        else if ($category = "Work") {
        $st_category = "Work";
        }
        else if ($category = "Money") {
        $st_category = "Money";
        }
        else if ($category = "Kids") {
        $st_category = "Kids";
        }
        else if ($category = "Health") {
        $st_category = "Health";
        }
        else if ($category = "Friends") {
        $st_category = "Friends";
        }
        else if ($category = "Education") {
        $st_category = "Education";
        }
        else if ($category = "Other") {
        $st_category = "Other";
        }
        else {
        header("Location: http://www.inelmo.com/");
        exit;
        }

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stories WHERE showing = 1 AND st_category = '$st_category' ORDER BY st_date DESC LIMIT 10") or die (mysql_error("There was an error in connection"));
        //And another stuff here to display article
?>
```

Comment: Have you checked that `$_GET['name']` is passing on a value to `$category`?

Comment: Use switch if you can't use if-else

Comment: what is that # in preg_replace. regexes are delimited by a \ right? Also check if $_GET['name'] has any value?

Comment: @Rawb92 oh true it doesn't seem to pass corect one, when I enter ?name=Health it returns Love.

Comment: @ShantanuD: First of all, traditionally it's `/`, not `\ ` ; second, it doesn't matter - `preg_replace` will take almost anything as the regex delimiter; that part is correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That could be tidied up to much less code, much more maintainable, using [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

```
$categories = array(
  'Love',
  'Work',
  'Money',
  'Kids',
  'Health',
  'Friends',
  'Education',
  'Other'
);

$category = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#i', '', $_GET["name"]);

if (!in_array($category, $categories)) {
  header("Location: http://www.inelmo.com/");
  exit;
}

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stories WHERE showing = 1 AND st_category = '$category' ORDER BY st_date DESC LIMIT 10") or die (mysql_error("There was an error in connection"));
```

And this also fixes the problem that @matino rightly pointed out, which is that you were assigning and not comparing.

Comment: Only preg_replace isn't really efficient.

Comment: This works for me )) thank you, I need to wait 5 more minutes to accept the answer, what would you suggest instead preg_replace?

Comment: @Spikey21 true, but I can't really pass comment without seeing where that value  is built from - and it does do a useful job, stripping all non-alpha chars from the string effectively sanitises the user input for SQL, and I don't know of a more efficient way to do *that specific task*...

Comment: @IlyaKnaup, i would use strpos(), substr() or strstr().

Comment: @Spikey21 Yes, but the code to do the same job as that does - remove *every non-alpha* character from the string - using those functions would be enormous and not much (if at all) more efficient

Comment: @IlyaKnaup I'm loving the "add tory" link at the top of you website, I love a good tory... ;-)

Answer (score 9):

`=` is not the same as `==`. In your if statements you are doing assignments not comparison.
`if ($category = "Love")` should be changed to `if ($category == "Love")` (or to `if ($category === "Love")` and so on...

Answer (score 4):

You have used a single "=" in every if.
The correct syntax is with "==" or "===", like:

```
<?php
    $category = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#i', '', $_GET["name"]);

    if ($category == "Love") {
        $st_category = "Love";
    }
    else if ($category == "Work") {
        $st_category = "Work";
    }
    ...
?>
```

Comment: That's not even a syntax error - `=` is the assignment operator, so the code runs successfully, except that `$category` *becomes* `Love`. The computer dutifully does what the user *instructed* it to - it can't check what the user *wanted*, though ;)

Comment: yeah, thank :). I know that it is a 'real' syntax error, I wrote that because it was an error for what he needs :D

Comment: Syntax error != program flow error, please don't conflate them. Those are very different beasts. The code above is *not* a syntax error. If it were, the PHP interpreter would not be able to run the code.

Comment: I kown, is a "translation" problem, what I want to say in my original language (italian) is the same you wrote, but when I translate it in English it take a different meanings.
Answer edited ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please use double equal sign like

```
if($foo=="foo1")
```

Answer (score 0):

In your if-statements you used the `=` while you had to used the `==` sign. With the `=` you assign a value to a variable on the left, like `$sum = 1 + 2;` you wanted is `$sum==3`.